# Problema con Js y el evento onload

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

estoy intentando hacer que con el evento onload se me cargue un alert en una función. Es senzillo pero no me funciona nose porque. Codigo:

```js
function inicia(){
  alert("hola");
}
```

```html
<body onload="inicia()">
    <table style="width:50%"  border="1" text-align="right">
      <tr>
        <th>Producte</th>
        <th>Preu</th>
        <th>Quantitat en magatzem</th>
        <th>Compra</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Televisor</td>
        <td align="right">500</td>
        <td align="right" id="quantitat_televisors"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="compra_televisors" name="televisors" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nevera</td>
        <td align="right">400</td>
        <td align="right" id="quantitat_neveres"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="compra_neveres" name="neveres" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
        <br/>


    <input type="button" value="Factura" onclick="omple_cookies_compra();">
        <input type="button" value="Reomple magatzem" onclick="reomple();">
        <input type="button" value="Esborra cookies" onclick="esborraCookies();">
    </body>
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que no te funciona? A mí si que me aparece el alert cuando ejecuto tu script.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que tengas una instrucción tal que así en tu html ya sea en el head o en el body:

```
<script src="ruta/tuarchivo.js"></script>
```

**la ruta** =  tu ruta al archivo que debe estar **bien escrita**, me parece que es ahí donde tienes el problema.

**tu archivo** = el nombre del archivo js bien escrito y no te olvides del .js

Luego en tu archivo.js debe estar la función:

```
function inicia(){
  alert("hola");
}
```